# Should I add cursor:pointer to pseudo class :hover or not?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I don't know, what should I use

```
.myclass {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

or

```
.myclass:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or there is no difference?

Comment: Sounds logical that there is no difference. I'd not put it on hover.

Comment: I think about other pseudo classes.. E.g. for :active cursor may be default (if I'd add cursor:special only for :hover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference - [the cursor will change in either case](http://jsfiddle.net/UaFnR/).

Answer (score 3):

Use whatever you want.
 I'd use the first one for it will save me a few lines of CSS

Otherwise you can specify a different pointer for all other pseudo classes.

like:

```
a:link{cursor:pointer;} /* you still dont need it ... as it's default*/
a:hover{cursor:crosshair;}
a:active:{cursor:wait;}
a:visited{cursor:wait;}
```

Comment: Useful for submits and buttons, however.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you need to support IE7, using the :hover pseudo class can cause the page to jump around erratically if the elements with the styled cursor are close to the bottom of the page. I recommend not using :hover since CSS will work fine without it.